# Math formula for drawing webkit-like rounded borders

Tags: css, math, canvas, border

In canvas i want to draw rounded corners in the same way as in webkit-base (google chrome) browsers. For example in css, I could have defined div like that:

```
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
  border-left: 20px solid green;
}
```

Live example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fHmt9/

How can I draw green border from this example in canvas? What is a math formula for this?